# Yet another FastCGI Primary Script Unknown error (nginx, php5-fpm)

Tags: php, nginx

This is my error.log from nginx:

> 2014/10/02 14:51:29 [error] 15936#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 134.106.87.55, server: sumomo.shitteru2.net, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "sumomo.shitteru2.net"

this is my enabled site:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name sumomo.shitteru2.net;

     index index.php index.html index.htm;

     location / {
             root /mnt/firstsite;
     }

     location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
             if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                     return 404;
             }
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

As far as I can see everything is very simple so it should work. I even copied it directly from http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample#Connecting_nginx_to_PHP_FPM. Do you guys see any potential problems?

Comment: Take a look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/517190/nginx-1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution I can use everywhere in /etc/nginx/snippets/common.conf:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location ~ \.php$
{                                                                                
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;                                                                                      
    # With php5-fpm:                                                                                                        
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;    
}
```

And now all my site config files look very simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name do-it-big.com www.do-it-big.com;
    root /var/www/doitbig;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    include snippets/common.conf;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```